# Failed to create void 'adc'

Tags: android-studio

estoy realizando un proyecto de fin de curso de mi instituto. Es acerca de compra de tickets para cine de manera digital. Esta siendo desarrollada por android studio, el problema es que cuando quiero usar una AVD me sale el siguiente error:

> Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
>
> Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
>
> Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
>
> Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

He intentado solucionar el problema pero nada funciona, espero que puedan ayudarme. Desde ya, muchas gracias!!.

Comment: Cuando quieres usar el AVD obtienes el error que hace referencia a audio, pero ¿que estas realizando o solo estas abriendo la aplicación en el AVD y marca el error?, te sugiero agregues más información, saludos.

Comment: NeroGames te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!